# A good ocaml parser?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, parsec

I'm looking for a good ocaml parsing library that isn't a derivative of flex/bison. Ideally, I'd like a monadic combinator library along the lines of parsec, but I can't find anything.

I would use haskell, but making llvm bindings for haskell is proving more tiresome than I originally thought.

Cheers,

Duane

Comment: Do you want a parser for OCaml as an input language, or a parser generator with OCaml as an implementation language/

Comment: hi duane, as someone interested in the same thing, i would like to know if you found a decent library in the end, and how it worked out for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here's one library](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatParserCo.html), via Google. (Which also brought up [this](http://osp.janestreet.com/files/pcl.pdf) and [this](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=0&browse=96), which lists several more relevant-sounding libraries.)

When I wrote a combinator parser in ML, it turned out rather cumbersome to use because of the value restriction and eager evaluation, which forced you to eta-expand your grammar rules. Ocaml is said to be more relaxed about the value restriction, though -- maybe you'll be spared some of that pain.

Comment: I'm a parser combinator newbie, but in seems that FParsec doesn't force you to eta-expand (and F# has value restriction and eager evaluation). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC this came up with recursive or mutually-recursive productions. Not everything's naturally expressed in a Kleene star. It's been over a decade since I did this, though -- hard to remember the problems.

Comment: @Mauricio: F# has the monad-like notion of computation expressions; this syntactic jiggy-wiggy allows you to hide all of the unpleasantness.

Answer (score 3):

In the OCaml world, [stream-based parsers](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/parsing.html) and [Camlp4](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Full_parser_tutorial) are the next two most common alternatives. Both have been described in detail in previous [OCaml Journal](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/ocaml_journal/?so) articles.

Monadic parser combinators are comparatively rare in OCaml, largely because there are several higher-level and vastly more efficient libraries available.

Comment: I'm learning about parser combinators. When you say "several higher-level and vastly more efficient libraries available", which ones do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Also, how would they compare to FParsec?

Comment: I'm referring to camlp4, ocamllex, ulex, ocamlyacc, dpygen, menhir, ocfgc, aurochs and others. I found that ocamllex and ocamlyacc were generally several times faster at parsing than anything available for F# such as fslex, fsyacc and FParsec.